# 18.04 - Cronjob Not Working on Reboot

Tags: cron, logs

I have recently added the following commands to the crontab :

```
@reboot macchanger -r eth0
@reboot macchanger -r wlan0
```

This worked perfectly and I used it this way for a couple weeks, then I added a wireless card so I went back in and added wlan1 to the cronjob.

```
@reboot macchanger -r eth0
@reboot macchanger -r wlan0 
@reboot macchanger -r wlan1
```

But when I reboot, wlan1 still has not been operated on by macchanger.

I tried to look for the cron.log but I couldn't find one.

```
root@kali-sony:/var/log# locate cron | grep log
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate
/usr/share/doc/anacron/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/anacron/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/cron/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/cron/changelog.gz
```

1) Does anyone have any hints about why that third, nearly identical cronjob isn't running like the other two?

2) Does anyone know why I can't seem to locate a cron log?

I am surprised this wasn't already asked, seems like I can't be the first person to have this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Update: with the help of @steeldriver I learned how to read the cron logs. I ran `journalctl -u cron.service` and was able to determine that all three commands ran without error but for some reason - wlan1 still reflects it's original, burned in MAC address.

Comment: On systemd-based systems, you can examine the cron logs using `journalctl -u cron.service`